# Can anyone suggest me how to store images into firebase's storage section manually (not by programmatically)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

**Can anyone suggest me how to store images into firebase's storage section manually (not by programmatically)?**

I wanna access those images for automatic image slider.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: its pretty simple, goto console, then storage then upload file there

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbdulKawee

Answer (score 0):

You basically go to google cloud and select the storage bucket for the relevant project, you can then drag drop, add and delete through there.

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/my-project.appspot.com/
```

There is also a way to make all files in the storage bucket accessible (Read) to the public by default

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public
```